# What it's not 'doesn't that' here in the sentence?

Tags: grammar

The following context comes form Breakfast at Tiffany's page 17. After Mr. Arbuck sent Holly home, but Holly closed the door in his face. Then Arbuck said:

> "Hey, baby!" he said, for the door was closing in his face. "Yes,
>   Harry?" "Harry was the other guy. I'm Sid. Sid Arbuck. You like me."
>   "I worship you, Mr. Arbuck. But good night, Mr. Arbuck." Mr. Arbuck
>   stared with disbelief as the door shut firmly.
>    "Hey, baby, let me in, baby. You like me, baby. I'm a liked guy.
>   Didn't I pick up the check, five people, your friends, I never seen
>   them before? ***Don't that give me the right you should like me***? You like
>   me, baby."

**My question is** why it's ***"don't'*** but not ***'doesn't'*** in the bold sentence? As 'that' here represents the fact that Arbuck pick up the check for Holly and her friends.

Comment: "Breakfast at Tiffany's" is a work of fiction. The character is a crude and violent man who speaks in ungrammatical English. Constructions like _I never seen_ and _Don't that give me_ are Capote's way of presenting this character.

Answer (score 2):

This is dialogue from a novel. That means it's how people talk. How they really talk, y'know?

Different social strata have different speech anomalies. In some, *don't* is used instead of *doesn't* in the 3rd person singular, presumably because it sounds more informal.

I'm surprised you didn't pick up on the other dialectical oddities, especially

> Didn't I pick up the check, five people, your friends, I never seen them before?